# Java file path relativization with jump-ups in relative path

Tags: java, java-7, filepath, relative-path, java-io

I just searching for some method in Java 7 which can correctly relativize file path.

Original destination:
"some/folder/over/here/123/456/original.txt"

Link destination:
"some/folder/over/there/abc/efg/link.txt"

so relative path for link should look like this:
"../../../there/abc/efg/link.txt"

Is there some method which can relativize path like this?

Thanx. Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built-in method in the `Path` called `relativize`.

More info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)